# How to decide which function to choose only dependent on type of the assigned value in java

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class

```
public class MyItems {
    ItemA myItemA1 = new ItemA();
    ItemA myItemA2 = new ItemA();
    ItemB myItemB1 = new ItemB();
}
```

Is it possible implement a Factory/Creator class so that the class can be changed to :

```
public class MyItems {
    ItemA myItemA1 = Factory.create();
    ItemA myItemA2 = Factory.create();
    ItemB myItemB1 = Factory.create();
}
```

or perhaps to

```
public class MyItems {
    ItemA myItemA1 = Factory.create<>();
    ItemA myItemA2 = Factory.create<>();
    ItemB myItemB1 = Factory.create<>();
}
```

I'm thinking about the assignment of lists:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

where you also have only the diamond on the right-hand side.

**Note:** You can introduce generics to the *ItemX* objects if necessary

Comment: No. The factory method can't guess what it should create if you don't tell it by passing an argument. The ArrayList constructor is different: it always constructs an ArrayList, and doesn't need to know the concrete generic type to create it. Kotlin can do that with its support for reified type parameters, but not Java, where reified type parameters don't exist.

Comment: Normally you'd use different methods for this, something like `Factory.createA()` and `Factory.createB()`.

Comment: When taking into account your note, you could (if it makes sense) turn ItemA, ItemB, and ItemC into Item<T> and use a factory method to create an Item<T>

It only makes sense if Item is, in some sense, a container for the concrete types

Comment: `ItemA myItemA2 = Factory.create();  ItemB myItemB1 = Factory.create();` How would you imagine `Factory.create()` to know what to return? In your first code block you explicitly say what the constructor is, so now when you take this info away, how would you like it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The closet possible thing to what you are trying to do would be something like

```
ItemA myItemA1 = (ItemA) Factory.create<ItemA>();
```

or

```
ItemB myItemB1 = Factory.createItemB();
```

since as already mentioned, the Factory can't guess what type to return (it can't even return different types, thus the cast is necessary). If you can come up witth some logic that allwos the Factory to guess the return-type 100% the time something like `ItemA myItemA1 = (ItemA) Factory.create()` could work, but it would absolutely wreck readability of your code, so don't do it.

There is one instance of this Problem, where `Factory.create()` can pe implemented without any issues: when all your `ItemX`-Types are interfaces. In that case you could create a class

```
public class ItemGeneric implements ItemA, ItemB, ItemC {
     //implementation off all three interfaces here
}
```

and let your factory alwaxs return a `ItemGeneric`.